# Facebook: What to do when run out of invitation quota when debugging invitation form?

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe

There's a invitation quota limitation for Facebook <fb:multi-friend-selector>, and I wrapped it inside <fb:request-form>, in iframe mode

I'm the application developer myself, and I have my own additional form data to add into the request-form

However when I debug this function, facebook only allows me to invite for 3 times only.
I have a few accounts to test, but all the quota will soon run out after intensive debugging.

Apart from opening new facebook accounts to debug, is there any other ways to bypass the invitation quota limitation within the developer accounts of the same application?

Many thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact facebook and state your problem, they might relax the limitation for your special application developer account, or grand you access to a special developer's sandbox (if they have one).
In no way should you try to work around their limitations without their consent, it will only piss of the admins and probably block your account/application.

Comment: To me I think developer sending invite to another developer of the same application shouldn't use up the quota.

Comment: Facebook is notably paranoid about massive invitation spam.  I wouldn't expect them to implement too many loopholes, given the increase in attack surface they imply.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at my question. [Facebook: Limit on Invites when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808790/facebook-limit-on-invites-when-debugging). I faced a similar situation. Facebook calculates the limit of the number of invitations a user can send from using your application, based on the acceptance rate of the invites. So once you send out an invite, open the facebook account to which you sent the invite to and accept the invite. I did this and I was able to send out many invites. However, I did hit a limit. A user cannot send infinite invites on a single day from your app, even if all the invites are accepted.

To summarize, to increase the limit of the number of requests, accept the invites you send out.

Answer (score 0):

Rather create legit facebook test accounts, having multiple accounts in a violation of the FB terms of service and could land you in trouble.  So rather check out test accounts.