# Facebook: Limit on Invites when debugging

Tags: facebook

I'm developing a Facebook application and currently testing out the invite feature. There is a limit on the number of invites that a user can send out using an application, defined by Facebook. However, I need to test the invite function's callback processing, so I sent out 5 or 6 invites to my test FB accounts, and now it says I can't send any more invites for the day. I'm using `<fb:request-form>` and I need to debug the script to which this tag posts to. So how do I override this invite limit?

Comment: That's like asking how do I suspend gravity for a minute while I do my testing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer. According to this post: http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=2318966938&topic=4554 FB calculates the acceptance rates of your invites and decides how many invites an app can send out. So in the test account to which I sent the invites, I accept all the invites from my application. And now FB allows me to send more invites from my app.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried contacting Facebook?  Perhaps they will be willing to relax the restriction for your testing or may have an alternative testing environment without this restriction.  You are not going to be able to bypass their server restrictions unless you use multiple accounts, which I would not recommend as you may trigger security measures they may have in place.